# Shiny inputs into mysql database

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

I am new to R and shiny. I want to build an app using R studio where there will occur some cases where user input is needed to be stored in a database. I am comfortable using Mysql. Here my problem is that the user data input is not getting stored in the database.

Where am I wrong?

#### Server

```
library(RMySQL)

options(mysql = list(
"host" = "localhost",

"user" = "root",
"password" = "mysql"
))
databaseName <- "myshinydatabase"
table <- "responses"

saveData <- function(data) {
# Connect to the database
db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = databaseName, host = options()$mysql$host, 
              port = options()$mysql$port, user = options()$mysql$user, 
              password = options()$mysql$password)
# Construct the update query by looping over the data fields
query <- sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ('%s')",        table,input$name,input$data) 
 # Submit the update query and disconnect
dbGetQuery(db, query)
dbDisconnect(db)
 }

 loadData <- function() {
 # Connect to the database
 db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = databaseName, host =    options()$mysql$host, 
              port = options()$mysql$port, user = options()$mysql$user, 
              password = options()$mysql$password)
 # Construct the fetching query
 query <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s", table)
 # Submit the fetch query and disconnect
 data <- dbGetQuery(db, query)
 dbDisconnect(db)
 data

 }
```

#### UI

```
 library(shiny)
 shinyUI(
 fluidPage(div(
            textInput("name","Name",""),
            numericInput("data","Data",""),

            actionButton("submit","Submit","")
 ))
 )
```

Comment: You can add `print(query)` right after construction to see if you construct a a valid query.

Comment: Thank you  but its not working..it is showing warning       Warning: Error in server: unused arguments (input = list(impl = <environment>, readonly = TRUE, ns = function (x) 
x), output = list(impl = <environment>, ns = function (x) 
x))
Stack trace (innermost first):
    40: server
     1: shiny::runApp
Error in server(...) : 
  unused arguments (input = list(impl = <environment>, readonly = TRUE, ns = function (x) 
x), output = list(impl = <environment>, ns = function (x) 
x))

Comment: So where is your `server <- function(input, output)` line? Take a look at basic `server.R` structure.

Comment: Okkk.....wont "saveData <- function(data)" and "
 loadData <- function()" work ??? I thought these two functions will do..Sorry :-P

Comment: please help me with the server.r script.

Comment: You can start [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson1/).

Comment: you seem very knowledgeable...could you please write the server.r script for above case.